# Chromium application not supporting what's app web?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, chromium, 32-bit, whatsapp

I am using the Ubuntu 16.04, browser Chromium is not supporting what's app web feature, it says this feature available in above 36.0 version of chrome.
this is not possible for me to install the chrome 32bit version in my system. It is available in chrome not in chromium.

Comment: What is your question? Also, do you use 16.04 as stated in text or 14.04 as tag says? Is your hardware 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit